# Creating new files through loop using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Dataset, which has 5 folders, in which each folder has 100 .txt files. Below code you can see that I am looping through every file, and removing certain words from those files using my StopWords.txt file.

After I remove the words I am appending the output in one file(filteredtext.txt). But I want to have these output exactly as my Dataset (5 folders which has 100 .txt file).

This is my code.

```
import re
import os

#insert stopwords files
stopwordfile = open("StopWords.txt", encoding='utf-8')  

# Use this to read file content as a stream:  
readstopword = stopwordfile.read() 
stop_words = readstopword.split() 

#file path to dataset
for path, _, files in os.walk("sinhala-set1"):
    for file_name in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        
        print(f"Checking --> {filepath}")
               
        file1 = open(filepath, encoding='utf-8')  

        # Use this to read file content as a stream:  
        line = file1.read() 
        words = line.split() 
        
        for r in words:  
            if not r in stop_words:  
                appendFile = open('filteredtext.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')  
                appendFile.write(" "+r)  
                appendFile.close()
```

Comment: So.. do you want us to help you create a file from python?

Comment: Ok, you have given some context and some code, which is good. But what is your precise question? Or what is wrong with the current code?

Comment: So instead of opening `'filteredtext.txt'` for writing every time, why not do something like `os.path.join(path, 'filtered_' + file_name)`? Have you tried anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the file because you are opening the same .txt file with appending mode `appendFile = open('filteredtext.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')` If you want a separate file for each loop, open a different file like this:

`output_file = open('output_' + file_name), 'w', encoding='utf-8')`